# Embedding Foxit PDF Reader into a webpage

Tags: pdf, deployment, object-tag, foxit

I need to embed Foxit Reader (PDF reading software) into a web page.  Does anybody know the correct classid and parameters to use in the following code:

```
<object id="pdfReaderObj" classid="CLSID:XXXX" width="500" height="700">
    <param name="Filename" value="/1234-56789-abc-123-3.pdf">
    <param name="SRC" value="/1234-56789-abc-123-3.pdf">
    You must install Foxit Reader to view this document.
</object>
```

Additionally if anyone has experience of enterprise deployment, silent installation, registry setting etc.  These would also be welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foxit Reader itself doesn't include any embeddable components; they have [Foxit Reader ActiveX](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/sdk/activex/) for this purpose, which is a paid component distributed separately from the Reader. For example, the Standard ActiveX version can be embedded into a web page in the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript"">
function openFile() {
    document.getElementById("foxitReader").OpenFile("foo.pdf", "");
}
</script>

<body onload="openFile()">
    <object id="foxitReader"
        classid="clsid:DB2189DF-ABF4-445A-A4E5-BF32F2CEA4D9"
        width="800" height="600">
    <p>You must install Foxit Reader ActiveX to view this PDF file.</p>
    </object>
</body>
```

(I'm not a web developer, so this code may be far from perfect, but it should help you get the idea.)

If using Foxit Reader ActiveX is not an option for you, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html) which discusses other possible ways of displaying PDF content.